# Amazon S3 : The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256

Tags: amazon-s3

I am using Amazon S3. 
I get error The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.

Comment: Are you using SSL/TLS?

Comment: Please, add flavor and version of the SDK you're using.

Comment: $s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'version'     => 'latest',
    'region'      => 'us-west-1',
    'credentials' => true,
 'signature_version'=> 'v4'
]);