# The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 in php

Tags: php, amazon-s3, xampp

I was trying to upload the image to s3 bucket but i am getting this warning while upload

> S3::inputFile(): Unable to open input file:

using authorization method as

> $s3 = new S3(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey)

and while i was trying to get contents by using this  $s3->getBucket($bucketName)
return warning as

> The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256

Can anyone help me to resolve this

Comment: Well not unless you show us what authorisation method you are using

Comment: @RiggsFolly i updated my question and authorization method

Comment: @CPHPython i need to use another sdk for this ? can you give me some description about above link

Comment: @Satya the answer to that question explains the reason independently of the SDK you are using: `new S3 regions deployed after January, 2014 will only support V4`. Different SDKs S3 API's implementations normally share the same type of errors.

Comment: And just yesterday, the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41463674/amazon-s3-the-authorization-mechanism-you-have-provided-is-not-supported-plea?rq=1) was raised.